# Auto_Route package on flutter pub dev is throwing an error anytime I tried try run my app

Tags: flutter, dart, auto-route

I woke up today to code and notice that any new project that I will create and try to you use auto_route package it gives me this strange error message but I have configured everything well, run flutter clean and all the possible cache clear commands but is not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLxeE.png)